# Find complexity of building Hk matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, computational-complexity

I have matrix $H_1:$
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

And aim is to achieve $H_k$:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        H_{k-1} & H_{k-1} \\
        \overline H_{k-1} & H_{k-1} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

The basis is only disjunction. How to find minimal complexity $L(H_k)$ of this problem?

**EDIT:**

$H_2$
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

**EDIT 2:**

$H_1$ also can be interpreted as:
\begin{align}y_1 = x1 \cup x2 \\ y_2 = x2 
\end{align}

$H_2$ also can be interpreted as:
\begin{align}y_1 = x_1 \cup x_2 \cup x_3 \cup x_4 \\ y_2 = x_2 \cup x_4 \\ y_3 = x_3 \cup x_4 \\ y_4 = x_1 \cup x_4
\end{align}

Comment: Is $\overline H_{k-1}$ complex conjugation? How is $H_k$ defined? Could you give $H_2$ explicitly? It seems to me a $4\times 4$ matrix with entries $0$ and $1$. So why complex conjugation?

Comment: @DietrichBurde 1) i guess no, $\overline H_{k-1}$ mean invert all elements separately. 2) $H_{k}$ defined like I wrote, thats it. If we assume $k=3$ it will be simple matrix 8x8 3) All entries are integers

Comment: @DietrichBurde I've edited the question